# Can't login as root after changing permissions of /usr/bin

Tags: linux, permissions, fedora, root

I changed the folder permissions of `/usr/bin` to `777`. Now when I login to `root` user it shows "incorrect password".

Now I'm not able to do anything on this PC. How can I revert the permissions of `/usr/bin` without a terminal? I think I need to change them to `751`.

I can login via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>, but not into `root`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boot off the install CD but dont install, mount the folder, and change the permissions back.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use single user mode to fix this problem.

1. boot the computer and stop it in grub menu
2. edit the boot parameter, just append 'single' to your current linux kernel, and press ENTER
3. after booting, you will be in single user mode, with root permission (without password) and with very few services enabled
4. change the permission by 'chmod 751 /usr/bin'
5. reboot and done

Hope this will help you.

Comment: This is exactly what single-user mode is for. +1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to boot in command line mode first, I used ubuntu for a while(now I am always in fedora ), in ubuntu, when I try to change into root mode and enter the correct password, it show 'incorrect password', I did this in command line:
$ sudo passwd

Password:

Enter new UNIX password:

Retype new UNIX password:

then reboot,
hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

You first need to check Administration.
 (Or)

Open the terminal.
Type below command and hit Enter

```
sudo -i
```

Give your password.
Now, you have a sudo. check below command

```
sudo apt update
```

Hope this will help you.